# How do International Call Rerouting Apps work?

Tags: android-development

Since DTMF seems impossible on Android devices, I really wonder how it is possible to setup a direct dail service like Jinggling (http://www.jinggling.com/how_it_works.html). I realize one registers his phone number, but to what end?

Say a customer now dails an international number, the App intercepts the call, reroutes it to their own service but how gets the desired number transmitted? The whole point is that this is works without wifi-/data-connection, no VOIP. The only way I can imagine this to work is using SMS to exchange auth and other related data. Or am I missing something?

Comment: SIP trunks, perhaps?  (gateways between normal phone lines and the internet)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on this?

Comment: Well, no, not really, I've only dabbled a bit with the topic.  I was just giving you a term you could use as a starting point for your search.

Comment: Not an answer because I can't verify it, but from what I was told: the call is intercepted and immediately rerouted to the provider instead. The provider then places the call to the target from a server in the target number's local region, then they bridge the 2 calls (you to them, them to target).

Comment: That's what I am thinking, too. I just do not understand how their server/telephony system gets the desired number to dail through. Is there a way to attach the desired number to the number of the provider? something like 040-numberOfService#desiredNumber ? The other parts are very clear, I know I can intercept the dailed number, I know I could even hang up, receive an r-call and automatically pickup again. The only thing I am missing is how the desired number is transfered once the 'server' is called